# How to draw a Circle inside a Raster generated Canvas using PaperJs

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am using paperjs to create Raster and to do some drawings on top of a image. But i am unable to figure out on how to draw circles on top of my images after converting my image src to raster. My Application has multiple images in a single page and i will have to do drawings on all images. The below is the code that i am using to convert image src to Raster for drawing on top of images.

```
      for(i=0;i< imgLength;i++){
         dir = FILE_DIR+"/"+imgJPGList[i];

        imgid = imgJPGList[i].substr(0, imgJPGList[i].indexOf('.'));               

        midproj = new paper.Project(paper.view);
        var raster = new paper.Raster();

        raster.onLoad = function() {

        console.log('Successfully loaded image!');
        }
        raster.source = dir;

        document.getElementById('imgID').appendChild(raster.canvas);//imgID is my DIV
        $("#imgID").append($("<br/>"));

        circle = new paper.Path.Circle(new paper.Point(80, 50), 35);
        circle.strokeColor = 'red';

        //paper.setup(raster.canvas);
        //paper.view.draw();
        }
```

I am trying to achieve something like the one in the below link.

http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/TZBBb8IwDIX/SpVLQYLkMO1StBNXDtM4wg5ZsNK0aRzZhmqa9t/XtIhxsGQ/P3968o9KdgDVqGMP4lq1UQ4vZb5ZqsiyAFVvVYKx+piH1Xp3pnNaNprxSg4mQ92K5MaYbDNQxxrJG7kKUrCRTRisBzYjUh+S345B2u1CYDNgsrrLvn7mZuQgAdNEvgUYtYM0ybOjVLTfj1iH0t9TlXKBXIT78t1Kq/ezssqEHTjRT8BN9fK6XC5XmoWwhz1GLPia4FL/gzExTp6I/sGag7COkLy06930vS8C22cMSVg1p8/fPw==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what problems you're having (it would be good to include a symptom or two) but I can offer a few suggestions. BTW, I didn't know there was an onLoad event for rasters - thanks.

1. I've never used raster.canvas. The documentation states that referencing it causes paper to create a canvas. So it is creating a second canvas different from the one that the paper.Project creates or uses.
2. I'm not sure what passing paper.view to paper.Project does. paper.view is the currently active project's view - I can't tell what that is from the code excerpt.

If I were coding this it would look something like (meta code, so pardon errors):

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
// do whatever attribute setting needs to be done for canvas.

document.getElementById("#mydiv").appendChild(canvas);

paper.setup(canvas);

// now create a raster in the default, current layer of the paper project
var raster = new paper.Raster();
raster.source = "some URL";

// now create a new layer. it becomes the active layer for drawing
var layer = new paper.Layer();

// draw circles and other stuff. they go on the new layer.
```

The order of some of the things can be changed. Inserting the canvas could be triggered on the loading of the image, etc.

But given the information I have that's my stab at an answer.

Comment: Thankyou bmacnaughton i tried to follow your approach and i am now confident that i can do this I am adding both img src and canvas to my div and then trying to work on rastersetup on top of img in my javascript. This is what i am doing http://ideone.com/IvHaqo